# ASP.NET Programmatically inserting table rows from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple HTML table within a cshtml page. It is basically a single column, where I want to programmatically insert rows from the result of an `ajax` call.

```
        <table class="table" id="notestedtable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Not Tested
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Unit#1 
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

I use the `document.onload = NotTested("Site 001", "17/06/2015");` to call the function which then executes the `ajax`.

```
function NotTested(SiteId,TestDate) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/NotTested',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            siteid: SiteId, testdate: TestDate
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.Tubs.length; i++) {

                alert(result.Tubs);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The returned `Tubs` is a `string[]` where `Tubs[0] = "Tub 1"; Tubs[1] = "Tub 2" ...` and so on. I want each of the `Tub[]` to form a row in my table.

This is the C# in the controller:

```
       [HttpPost] // can be HttpGet
    public ActionResult NotTested(string siteid, string testdate)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //this could be populated first by reading for this "site" how many tubs to be expected
        string[] UnTested = new string[8];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=****;Database=****;User Id=****;Password=****;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TubsNotTested(@siteid,@testdate)", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteid",siteid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testdate", testdate);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for(i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            UnTested[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            Tubs = UnTested,
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the ajax success callback to

```
success: function (result) {
  $.each(result.Tubs, function(index, item) {
    var cell = $('<td></td>').text(item); // create the table cell
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').append(cell); // create the table row
    $('#notestedtable').append(row); // append the row to the table
  });
}
```

Side note: It would be better to include `var table=$('#notestedtable');` at the top of your script to cache the element and then use `table.append(row);` so avoid traversing the DOM again.

Comment: This should work, however you should use document.ready instead of document.onload, better using the $(function() { .... notation

Comment: I have implemented this and put an `alert(item)` under `$('#notestedtable').append(row);` and I get `Tub 6,,,,,,,` but nothing displayed in the table?

Comment: What does `console.log($('#notestedtable').length);` return?

Comment: Should be working fine. Are you sure `result` is and array? I'll create a fiddle for you shortly

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I have edited my original post to show the C# code behind the AJAX call ...

Comment: OK, your not returning an array, your returning an object with a property which is an array :). In the controller it should be `return Json(UnTested, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` or if you want the flexibility to add additional properties to the json, then in the ajax call it needs to be `$.each(result.Tubs, function(index, item) {` - i.e. access the `Tubs` property of the response

Comment: I have tried both modifications and still no rows appear, even though in console I can see the strings being returned

Comment: Apologies - stupid typo - its needs to be `$('<td></td>')` and ditto for `$('<tr></tr>')`. See also [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4jc9Lzr/)

Comment: No need to apologise when helping me :-) Thank you this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var table = document.getElementById("notestedtable");

    for (var i = 0; i < result.Tubs.length; i++) {

        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = result.Tubs[i];
        }
```